# Error occurs when trying to install mega.py using pip

Tags: python, api, pip, cloud

I was trying to install mega.py, for a project I'm working on that needs the files to be uploaded to the Mega Cloud Server, using the command `pip install mega.py` and the following is shown in the cmd.

```
Collecting mega.py
  Using cached mega.py-1.0.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
Collecting pycryptodome<4.0.0,>=3.9.6
  Using cached pycryptodome-3.14.1-cp35-abi3-win_amd64.whl (1.8 MB)
Collecting tenacity<6.0.0,>=5.1.5
  Using cached tenacity-5.1.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (34 kB)
Collecting pathlib==1.0.1
  Using cached pathlib-1.0.1.tar.gz (49 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [1 lines of output]
      ERROR: Can not execute `setup.py` since setuptools is not available in the build environment.
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Can anyone help me out in figuring out what I should do to resolve this? I've been trying out solutions for this problem for a long time now!

Comment: Your computer might not be able to install it.

Comment: Please, check [ask]. Don't post images of code, error, data, etc. Copy/paste as formatted text.

Comment: @buran I was not aware of that instruction... Thank you for letting me know!